# Autocompletar una caja de texto, con datos que se han ingresado

Tags: vb.net

Tengo un pequeño inconveniente, resulta que en un TextBox de VB tengo que escribir una clave de 15 digitos, pero dentro de esa cadena, las primeras 2 varían, las 6 que siguen es la misma información en todas las cadenas, el noveno digito debe ser igual al segundo, seguido de dos ceros (00) y de ahí los últimos 4 dígitos son variables.

Dentro del evento **`KeyDown`** del TextBox identifico un **`ENTER`** despues de escribir los 2 primeros digitos, lo que me falla es COPIAR el 2do digito a la novena posición.

Anexo código para ver si me pueden orientar.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            TextBox1.AppendText("243810_00")
        End If
    End Sub
```

El guion bajo se debe remplazar por el segundo digito del textBox que se ha ingresado. Espero darme a entender.

> Actualización

Ejemplos: Si en la caja de texto escribo:

- 18 debe autocompletar con 1`8`   243810`8`00
- 12 debe autocompletar con 1`2`   243810`2`00
- 20 debe autocompletar con 2`0`   243810`0`00

Comment: Personalmente, yo no lo entiendo. Puedes poner un par de ejemplo con los datos de entrada y cual debe ser el resultado final?

Comment: no entiendo. tu problema es que no sabes hacer un substring? ojo, capaz me estoy perdiendo algo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con `TextBox1.AppendText("243810" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(1, 1) & "00")` resolverías ese pequeño inconveniente!

Comment: Ojala no aprete enter antes de tener ese caracter escrito, y ojala no aprete enter despues de haber metido toda la cadena... :/

Comment: Al final lo deje asi  `If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
            If Len(TextBox1.Text) = 2 Then
                TextBox1.AppendText("243810" & TextBox1.Text.Substring(1, 1) & "00")
            End If
        End If ` Me garantiza que el calculo se realiza siempre y cuando ingrese 2 digitos en la caja de texto.